# What is a funcarg?

Tags: python, pytest

I was reading about pytest module and come up to the term "funcarg". I couldnt find any explanation for it. Found it in pytest doc page - https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/funcarg_compare.html . But initially found it in Python OOP book from Dusty Phillips:

Fixtures can do a lot more than return basic variables. A  request  object can be passed into
the fixture factory to provide extremely useful methods and attributes to modify the
funcarg's behavior.

Can someone provide some simple explanation?
Thank you.

Comment: function arguments

Comment: Check https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.0.3/funcargs.html

Comment: isn't that just a fancy word for fixture?

Answer (score 1):

A `FuncArg` is a function (a reference to it to be more exact) that you pass as an argument to a function.

The advantage of this is that the function is only executed in the function that you call. If that function 'decides' not to use it then you gained some performance since the function was not yet executed.